# Extract certain part of a string in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following Perl strings. The lengths and the patterns are different. The file is always named `*log.999`

```
my $file1 = '/user/mike/desktop/sys/syslog.1';
my $file2 = '/user/mike/desktop/movie/dnslog.2';
my $file3 = '/haselog.3';
my $file4 = '/user/mike/desktop/movie/dns-sys.log'
```

I need to extract the words before `log`. In this case, `sys`, `dns`, `hase` and `dns-sys`.

How can I write a regular expression to extract them?

Comment: You say "_**file** named XXXXlog.num_"  but your examples show a _directory_, `.../syslog.1/'` (note the trailing slash) -- which is it?  And, is this _always_ the last thing in the name/path?

Comment: @zdim sorry for the confusion. I meant the file's name(XXXXlog.num) is alway the last thing in the whole path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main property of shown strings is that the `*log*` phrase is *last*.

Then anchor the pattern, so we wouldn't match a `log` somewhere in the middle

```
my ($name) = $string =~ /(\w+)log\.[0-9]+$/;
```

while if `.N` extension is optional

```
my ($name) = $string =~ /(\w+)log(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/;
```

---

The above uses the `\w+` pattern to capture the text preceding `log`. But that text may also contain non-word characters (`-`, `.`, etc), in which case we would use `[^/]+` to capture everything after the last `/`, as pointed out in [Abigail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46289256/4653379).  With `.N` optional, per question in the comments

```
my ($name) = $string =~ m{ ([^/]+) log (?: \.[0-9]+ )? $}x;
```

where I added the `}x` modifier, with which spaces inside are ignored, what can aid readibility.

I use a set of delimiters other than `/` to be able to use `/` inside without escaping it, and then the `m` is compulsory. The `[^...]` is a *negated character class*, matching any character *not* listed inside. So `[^/]+log` matches all successive characters which are not `/`, coming before `log`.

The *non capturing group* `(?: ... )` groups patterns inside, so that `?` applies to the whole group, but doesn't needlessly capture them.

The `(?:\.[0-9]+)?` pattern was written specifically so to disallow things like `log.` (nothing after dot) and `log5`.  But if these are acceptable, change it to the simpler `\.?[0-9]*`

**Update**   Corrected a typo in code: for optional `.N` there is `+`, not `*`

Comment: Just a small question. Why we need to add parentheses to **my ($name)** rather then using   **my $name** ? @zdim

Comment: @Luke  What the match operator (`m/.../`) returns depends on the _context_.  In scalar context, which we have in `if ($v =~ /.../)` or in `$ret = $v =~ /.../` (etc), it returns true/false; In list context, it returns the actual list of matches.  So we need to impose list context on it, which is what the parens do `($match) = $v =~ /.../`.   Or we can say `@matches = $v =~ /.../` of course.

Comment: so in this case it returned true/ false right? I think my $filepath is scalar context.. So in order to convert true/false on it, then we need to use parens()?  I am not quite understand. Thanks so much @zdim

Comment: @Luke  This context business is about the _regex matching_.  With parenthesis it returns the actual match (not just true/false), so we get `sys` or such. (Without the parenthesis it would return 1 or empty string, for false!).  The filenames you show in the question are just a normal assignment, of a string to a variable.  No need for parenthesis there.

Comment: OH. GOTCHA. appreciate it.

Comment: What if I have strings with dash like Abigail said, how can I fixed the Regex based on your **.N optional** case. Let say `my $file2 = '/user/mike/desktop/movie/dns-sys.log';` How can I extract **dns-sys**?

Comment: @Luke  Updated the answer

Comment: @Luke  I've added more, and fixed a bad typo in the optional part. (It had `*` while it should have `+` to work as described.)  Thank you for making me look again.

Comment: Thanks for you clear explanation all the time, which is very helpful. I learn a lot about Regex from you. @zdim

Answer (score 2):

```
\w+(?=log\b)
```

matches one or more alphanumeric characters that are followed by `log` (but not `logging` etc.)

If the filename format is fixed, you can make the regex more reliable by using

```
\w+(?=log\.\d+\/$)
```

Comment: You could also do `(\w+)log\b`.